# Is there a way to send array on javascript to controller other than get or post method??

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net-mvc

I am using ASPX and C#.

Is there a way to send an array on javascript to controller other than get or post method, or ajax or jquery?

I tried use the Url.Action code but seem like unable to parse the value in javascript to it.

This is how I pass the value:

```
<% Url.Action("Action","Controller",new { item = %> users <%});%>
```

But it gave me an error on the Brace '}'. State that invalid expression term.

Comment: you cannot pass js variable to c#

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Javascript runs in the browser. The only way to communicate with the controller running on the server is through a http request such as GET or POST (or other HTTP verbs, or websockets or SignalR, but that's probably not applicable here).

`Url.Action` is a C# method that is called and evaluated entirely on the server, before producing the html sent to the browser. You can't reference a javascript variable in that call, so what you've tried is not only a syntax error. It is simply not possible to do that at all.